# ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list (why occurs?)

Tags: list, function

I just want to edit list using remove and append method

```
 input_list = ["SAS","R","PYTHON","SPSS"]
 import ast,sys
 input_list = (sys.stdin.read()).split(",")
 input_list.remove("SPSS")
 input_list.append("SPARK")
 print(input_list)
```

Then I get this error: ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you are doing with your *stdin* but you try to modify your list while you change its value.

```py
 input_list = ["SAS","R","PYTHON","SPSS"]
 # the list is correctly set

 import ast,sys # import... 

 input_list = (sys.stdin.read()).split(",")
 # you have changed the value of your list

 input_list.remove("SPSS")
 # so you can't remove this item if the list is changed. 
 # Maybe the new list doesn't contain "SPSS" item

 input_list.append("SPARK")
 # The append should work fine

 print(input_list) # print...
```

If you didn't give a right value in your *stdin*, obviously your *remove* has failed